# How to find and disable a specific startup script?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, autostart, xfce4-terminal

### Problem

A couple months ago I configured a startup script (or 3) to launch three terminal windows. Each terminal window is pointed to a specific directory and is set to a different window title. That used to be handy for my workflow back then but I don't need it anymore. Hence, I would like to remove that startup script.

However, I don't have notes and can't find out where this is configured.

### My efforts to try and just find the file

I looked through:

- `crontab -l`
- `sudo crontab -l`
- Super-key / Session and Startup / Application Autostart
- `/etc/init.d/` (with `grep`)
- `/etc/` (with `grep`)
- `/etc/rc.local` (doesn't exist)
- `/home/<me>/` (`grep` didn't finish)
- `/home/<me>/.config/autostart` (with `grep`)

The `grep` command I used was: `grep -rnw <path> -e "<terminal title>"`

Where else can I look?

### My attempt to find out directly who started the process

```
(base) <me>@<computer>:~$ ps -feww | grep <terminal title>
<me>       3285    2908  0 08:48 ?        00:00:04 xfce4-terminal --geometry=80x24 --display :0.0 --role=xfce4-terminal-1639742375-3239411715 --show-menubar --show-borders --hide-toolbar --active-tab --title spyder --working-directory <secret directory> --window --geometry=80x24 --display :0.0 --role=xfce4-terminal-1639661690-6171981 --show-menubar --show-borders --hide-toolbar --active-tab --title tools --working-directory <secret directory> --window --geometry=80x24 --display :0.0 --role=xfce4-terminal-1639673287-3476381957 --show-menubar --show-borders --hide-toolbar --active-tab --title <terminal title> --working-directory <secret directory> --sm-client-id 23b3eb66f-7b36-477f-a65e-7346441c04e8
<me>      20821    7138  0 12:29 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto <terminal title>
(base) <me>@<computer>:~$ ls /proc/3285
arch_status  cmdline          exe      loginuid   mountstats  oom_score_adj  sched         stack    timers
attr         comm             fd       map_files  net         pagemap        schedstat     stat     timerslack_ns
autogroup    coredump_filter  fdinfo   maps       ns          patch_state    sessionid     statm    uid_map
auxv         cpuset           gid_map  mem        numa_maps   personality    setgroups     status   wchan
cgroup       cwd              io       mountinfo  oom_adj     projid_map     smaps         syscall
clear_refs   environ          limits   mounts     oom_score   root           smaps_rollup  task
(base) <me>@<computer>:~$
```

I don't really know what to make of this information. Is there anything in there? Or is there some other way to find out who started the running process?

### EDIT: Another attempt to find out more:

```
(base) <me>@<computer>:~$ pstree -sp 3285
systemd(1)───lightdm(1529)───lightdm(2267)───xfce4-session(2908)───xfce4-terminal(3285)─┬─bash(3304)
                                                                                        ├─bash(3315)
                                                                                        ├─bash(3324)
                                                                                        ├─bash(4934)
                                                                                        ├─bash(7138)───pstree(24279)
                                                                                        ├─bash(11131)
                                                                                        ├─bash(15675)
                                                                                        ├─{xfce4-terminal}(3292)
                                                                                        ├─{xfce4-terminal}(3293)
                                                                                        └─{xfce4-terminal}(16374)
```

I have three terminal windows open. I don't understand what the seven `bash` processes are. `7138` seems to correspond to one of the terminals because there's `pstree` as a child.

Comment: Linux Mint is using GNOME. In GNOME, you have a configuration setting for "Startup programs" - programs/scripts that are run automatically when you log in. Maybe you configured your script there?

Comment: have a look at `pstree` as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1093198/957833)

Comment: Also if you know your terminal is PID 3285, and it's parent is PID 2908. So check the process 2908, then it's parent and in that way maybe you can trace it up to the point where this starts.

Comment: @raj 2908 that's just `xfce4-session`. Its init script at `~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc` doesn't exist and the global init script at `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc` doesn't appear to contain anything relevant.

Comment: So this must be somewhere in your GNOME session startup applications. I see no other option.

Comment: My Desktop interface is xfce4, not GNOME

Comment: Any chance you added some commands to `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bash_login` (whichever is present on your system) to start them? The first of these that the login shell finds is executed. I use xfce as well and set things up to have a couple things start from there.

Comment: Not sure if it would start terminals pointed at particular directories, but you might see if you have a "Saved Sessions" tab in the "Session and Startup" dialog. Shouldn't be there unless there are saved sessions. If it's there, you might try clearing any listed saved sessions, and perhaps unchecking "Automatically save session on logout" on the "General" tab if it's checked.

Comment: @DavidYockey nothing relevant in `~/.profile` and the other two files don't exist.

Comment: @DavidYockey there is a Saved Session there from December. I deleted it. If this turns out to be the one, I'll post it as an answer.